# Is it legal for an 18 year old moroccan man to sext a 17 year old vietnamese girl?

Tags: criminal-law, internet, international, is-x-legal

Say a hypothetical 18 year old man from morocco has been texting a vietnamese girl online, and they mostly just talk about hobbies and common interests but she started sexualizing the conversation, sending nudes... Would it be legal for him to reciprocate and ask her for more pics/videos? Knowing that in morocco extramarital affairs are illegal so there is technically no age of consent but there is no legislation for sexting, in vietnam I found sources that say 16 years old is the age of consent but I'm not sure, and I don't know what laws for sexting are. Oh and it's hypothetically not a scam.

Comment: It's worth noting that in some jurisdictions the age of consent and the age required for pornography are not the same

Answer (score 3):

It is illegal in Morocco to possess or distribute pornographic material of any kind. This includes nudes of the hypothetical Vietnamese girl.

Comment: could you cite a source on that, please?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I can though unfortunately none of the sources I have are Moroccan.